# I am not able to import pywhatkit in repl.it

Tags: python

I was making a program using `pywhatkit` to send WhatsApp messages. However, when trying to import `pywhatkit`, the following exception is raised:

[image: Error message]

(Sorry, I was not able to copy the error message.)

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: As the error suggests, it can't find the ```.XAuthority``` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the dependencies of `pywhatkit` is the `pyautogui` module (see [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) for what `pyautogui` is). REPL.it runs on Linux, a Unix-like OS; on Unix, `pyautogui` requires `Xlib` (hence, `Xlib.error.XauthError`). On importing `pywhatkit`, `Xlib` attempted to open the *.Xauthority* file, but failed to do so, in this case because the file does not exist. I believe this behavior has to do with REPL.it itself, i.e., there's nothing you can do about it.

*For background on what the .Xauthority file is, refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300682/what-is-the-xauthority-file) AskUbuntu question.*